# Data Table Escape Periods

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, datatables

I have a datatable created with datatable.js.

I set up my table using an object and columns with names:

```
{ "title": "image", "data": "foo1", "className": "dt-center" },
{ "title": "id", "data": "foo.bar", "className": "dt-center" },
{ "title": "name", "data": "lorem", "className": "dt-center" }
```

I am trying to dynamically add a row to it. I am doing this with the following code:

```
var Json = {
    "foo1" : '5',
    "foo.bar" : '3',
    "lorem" : 'True'
}
var rtn = oTable.fnAddData(Json );
```

The problem is, I am getting the [error](https://www.datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/4) *"Requested unknown parameter "foo.bar" for row n"*. [This](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.data) page indicates that periods need to be escaped with a `\\`. 
Unfortunately, this isn't reliable.

This is a table of the number of backslashes (`\`) I have used in each location.
[image]

How can I escape this so that it works in both places?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your original data is in the format shown below, that is the only explanation that the dotted notation (`foo.bar`) in [columns.data](http://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.data) worked initially.

```
{
   "foo1": '5',
   "foo": { "bar": '3'},
   "lorem": 'True'
}
```

Dotted notation (`foo.bar`) in [columns.data](http://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.data) allows to read from nested objects, so `foo.bar` refers to `bar` sub-property of property named `foo`.

You must pass data in the same format to `fnAddData`, so you need to use the code below:

```
var Json = {
    "foo1" : '5',
    "foo": { "bar" : '3' },
    "lorem" : 'True'
};

var rtn = oTable.fnAddData(Json);
```

See the example below for code and demonstration.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   
   var oTable = $('#example').dataTable({
     'columns': [
        { "title": "image", "data": "foo1", "className": "dt-center" },
        { "title": "id", "data": "foo.bar", "className": "dt-center" },
        { "title": "name", "data": "lorem", "className": "dt-center" }
     ]
   });
  
   var Json = {
      "foo1" : '5',
      "foo": { "bar" : '3' },
      "lorem" : 'True'
   };
  
   var rtn = oTable.fnAddData(Json );   
});
```

```html
<link href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! This is what I tried to demonstrate in the table in my question. Using `\\.` in the column declaration and `.` in the new row worked fine for the new row, but did not allow for the old data (that I was previously reading in to foo.bar, passed in by the data parameter to the table) to populate.

Comment: @Cptn_Hammer, I think I understand the problem now, I rewrote my answer.

Comment: Hey that worked! I had given up hope. I upvoted this before the update, or I'd do it again! Thank you! If anyone looks at this in the future, it's not that I had a `.` in my name (or the `\\` probably would have worked) it's (as Gyrocode.com mentioned) that I actually had an object.

Answer (score 0):

It is most likely a problem with the plugin code itself.  Try eliminating the period entirely from the JSON key value `foo.bar`

Comment: No such luck. For now I'm using a workaround by setting sDefaultValue equal to what I want. As long as I don't want to send a different value to the newly created row (which at the time I don't) it solves the problem.

Comment: create a JSfiddle, and that should help everyone debug your issue easier/faster